# Moving a channel to a category with a specific name

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to run a command in a server that will move that channel to the archive category that I created. I don't want to use the category ID (if possible, to use the name of the category, "archive" as I will be running it in multiple servers.)

I am not sure what to put when I edit the channel.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def archive(ctx):

    channel = ctx.channel

    await channel.edit()
    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [discord.utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.utils.get).

```
archive = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name="archive")
await ctx.channel.edit(category=archive)
```